# How to get top two salaried employees in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to get top two employees based on salary from a department,

Department Schema ::

```
const departmentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    employee_id: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'employee' }]
})
```

Employee Schema ::

```
const employeeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
    },
    salary : {
       type: Number
    }
})
```

Let's say I have document in department schema as ::

```
{
    "_id":ObjectId("615851c162a012f82cc5bdf6"),
    "name":"abc",
    "employee_id":[ 
        ObjectId("615852d062a012f82cc5d54d"), 
        ObjectId("6158530462a012f82cc5d9c8"),
        ObjectID("6158530462a012f82cc8e1b9")
    ]
}
```

And document in employee as ::

```
{
    "_id":ObjectId("615852d062a012f82cc5d54d"),
    "name":"john",
    "salary":12345
}

{
    "_id":ObjectId("6158530462a012f82cc5d9c8"),
    "name":"smith",
    "salary":999
}

{
    "_id":ObjectId("6158530462a012f82cc8e1b9"),
    "name":"Alex",
    "salary":99999
}
```

Based on this I want to get details of top two employees based on their salary.

For this I tried as:

```
   await department.aggregate([
        { $match : { name : 'abc' } },
    ]).populated('employee_id')
```

But it throws error populate is not a function. How can I work for the same as I am very much in MySQL but not familiar with mongodb? If anyone needs any further information please do let me know.

Expected response as ::

```
[
    {
        "_id":ObjectId("6158530462a012f82cc8e1b9"),
        "name":"Alex",
        "salary":99999,
         department: abc
     },
     {
        "_id":ObjectId("615852d062a012f82cc5d54d"),
        "name":"john",
        "salary":12345,
        department: abc
      }
]
```

Comment: i think it's better if your `employeeSchema` has `departmentId` field rather than your `departmentSchema` has array field of `employeeId` IMO

Comment: your function is `populated`. it should be `populate`

Comment: populate also gives the same error

Comment: I want to match with department and then from that department get the list of suppliers.

Comment: The question seems to be a mixture of 1) mongoose populate syntax error and 2) mongodb query to get top 2 employee. For question 2), you may see this [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Pl2Vt_1ORC1) to see if it suits your need.

Comment: Thank you for your time and this solution is exactly what I was looking for but when I try to get data in node it gives value as::

const data = process in playground

console.log(data)

Aggregate {
  _pipeline: [
    { '$match': [Object] },
    { '$lookup': [Object] },
    { '$unwind': [Object] },
    { '$replaceRoot': [Object] }
  ],
  _model: Model { department },
  options: {}
}

How can I resolve it

Comment: First thing first, please dont past code in comment. Instead, please update your new trial in your question.

Comment: and for a brief look, I think _model option should put `employee` instead of `department` ? as we are returning employee documents

Comment: sorry for that I have updated in the question.

Comment: @ray I followed the exact same steps and it returned department for me.

Comment: @ray Thank you it is working fine...i just had to use await to get the result. Can you please put the solution in answer box so I can mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the followings in an aggregation pipeline:

1. `$match` to select the expected `department` document
2. `$lookup` from `employee` collection with a subpipeline
3. In the subpipeline of step 2, use `$match` to filter out expected employee records
4. In the same subpipeline , `$sort` by salary and `$limit` to get top 2 employee
5. use `$addFields` to add the department name to the employee object
6. `$unwind` the subpipeline result
7. `$replaceRoot` to get the employee documents

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MNDXflsF2CF) for your reference.

Comment: Can I ask one additional question or should I create new question? 

My query:: Can I get department's name as well in the response?

Comment: As your update seems a small one, I think it may be fine that you just update the format of your expected response in the original question.

Comment: updated the answer and playground link